# Pandas - find the index satisfying conditions of each row

Tags: python, pandas, sklearn-pandas

I tried to find the index which satisfy certain conditions in pandas DataFrame.

For example, we have the following dataframe

[image]

and find  the index such that

```
argmin(j) df['A'].iloc[j] >= (df['A'].iloc[i] + 3 ) for all i
```

so the result will be given by

[image]

I finished the work by using for loop, but I believe there is more efficient way to acheieve this job.

Thank you for your reply!

My code is

```
for i in range(len(df)):
    df['B'].iloc[i] = df[df2['A']>= df2['A'].iloc[i]+1].index[0]
```

but, for loop is too slow for a large data set.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please don't post links to screenshots of data - just include example data inline, instead.  That makes it easier for people to help you, and it protects against the possibility of links becoming dead in the future.

Comment: create minimal working example so everyone could run it and make modifications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try following method, :)

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1,3,5,8,10,12]})
b = pd.DataFrame(df.values - (df['A'].values + 3), index=df.index)
df['B'] = b.where(b >= 0).idxmin()
df
```

Comment: Thank you! It helps me a lot!